# In the slick grid list section header menu pop-up is not scrollable

Tags: slickgrid, angular-slickgrid

I have an angular-slick grid with an enabled header menu option. I want to scroll down and use the other option in the slick grid header menu. But we cant able to use the scrolling option. This is an issue I'm facing in the slick grid header menu.

**Current Behavior**

- We cant use the **remove filter option** and the appearance of the header menu is not good.
- We cant scroll the header menu. So this is our a major issue.

[image]

**Expected Behavior**

- Is any solutions like to **increase the Div height** or else we **put a scroll** for the header menu.

Kindly provide the solution for this UI issue in the slick grid.

**Software Version**

- Angular : 11.2.18
- Angular-Slickgrid : 2.30.4
- TypeScript : 4.1.5
- Operating System : Windows 10
- Node : 14.18.3
- NPM : 6.14.8

Comment: the only way to fix this would be to append the header menu div to the `body` since the z-index doesn't work because of the CSS that SlickGrid uses. This would require a lot of work, too much work, and for that reason I will not fix this. Typically if your grid is that small, you could provide a `minHeight` to the `autoResize` grid option, at least to the height of the header menu and that would fix your problem, header menu should never be really tall anyway